# "to call a lift" is idiomatic in this context?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Let's assume I'm on the 1st floor, but in order to go by the lift to the 5th floor, you have 2 ways: 1. To use a chip that unlocks the lift (like hotel cards). 2. ask a person (for instance, a secretary) on the 5th floor, *to press the button* for you.

Now, if I want to ask the person to do it for me on the 5th floor, I can just ask him simply: "*Can you press the button for me?*" But I'm looking for an idiomatic option. I've found myself recently saying: *"Can you **CALL** the lift?*", but I'm not sure if it's idiomatic. Is it?

Comment: Yes. In the UK you sometimes see buttons to press with a label saying 'CALL LIFT' or 'SUMMON LIFT'.

Comment: "call the lift" means "get the lift here", it's not clear if you mean that or if you want the lift sent to a floor you're not currently on.

Comment: You push a button to call a lift or elevator. It is the only way to say it.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience of lifts (elevators) in the UK and Europe, you press a button on your own floor to call the lift to you.

If for some reason the system involved asking someone on another floor to operate the controls, I would say "Can you send the lift to the first floor, please?"